# Get function handle that were created using exec()

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm creating a function dynamically, and trying to pass the handle to a class for pickling:

```
def my_func():
    exec("""def my_collate_fn():
    pass""")

    loader = DataLoader(collate_fn=my_collate_fn)
```

This code above will throw an error saying that `my_collate_fn` is not defined. Weird thing is that during debugging, the handle did actually exist and I can see it under local scope, but it throws error during runtime. Is there something I missed?

For context I'm strongly avoiding `lambda` since Pytorch's `DataLoader` class can't pickle them if number of workers greater that 0.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Can you show exactly how you're implementing this code and what error you're getting at runtime?

Comment: An easy fix is adding the `globals()` argument after the string: `exec(str, globals())`.  Of course, only use `exec` if you absolutely trust the input source.

Comment: @C.Nivs I just edited the question with the snippet

Comment: @oda is there a short code to demonstrate that? EDIT: Looks like you did in the edited comment.

Comment: So your first argument to `exec` is `"""def my_collate..."""`. Add the second argument `globals()`. Then after the `exec` call, just add the statement `print(my_collate_fn)` . Then call the function and you should see it is defined.

Comment: That actually fixed it. I wonder why? Is there a technical explanation for this why local scope will throw the error, but not global?

Comment: Btw, if you don't want `my_collate_fn` to be global, you can call `exec` how you originally called it. A reference to `my_collate_fn` can be obtained via `locals()['my_collate_fn']` from within your function. Try doing `exec` how you originally called it followed by `print(locals()['my_collate_fn'])`. Of course you can also call this function by adding parentheses afterwords.

Comment: @Oda - you said above ".... Add the second argument globals(). " - actually, the current global namespace is used inside `exec` implicitly: passing `globals()` is just the same as passing no second argument at all. Passing an arbitrary dictionary, on the other hand, will keep things well behaved, as no code inside the string will mess with the global namespace.

Comment: @GregorIsack: Function locals aren't actually a `dict`; they're a fixed size array, where the indices in the array are associated with specific strings (known variable names) at compile-time. `exec` can't expand the array (the function is already compiled, the size and associations are fixed now), and can't introduce new name-to-index mappings. `locals()` gives you a *copy* of the locals mapping names to values, but it's not mutable (not in cases where it's representing an actual set of function locals anyway). Sending the result to `globals()` (always a `dict`) works around the issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: @jsbueno Try it. Python 3.10. Just create a function `foo` that calls `exec` with one string argument of a function definition for `foo2` (with a `pass` statement). Then add a print statement to print `globals()`. Then add a print statement to print `foo2`. Then call `foo`. You will get to see the globals dictionary just before `NameError` is raised. Do the same thing but this time add `globals()` as the second argument to exec. Then you don't get `NameError` anymore. Now, if you were to do the same thing above, without arguments to `exec`, and reference `foo2` using `locals()`, it works.

Comment: I have seen standard library modules use `exec` within classes by passing in `globals()` as the second argument by default followed by `local_ns` (a dictionary we create ourselves). Then they call the function through the reference in `local_ns`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `exec`you may pass two additional parameters with dicionaries representing the global and local namespaces where the code is run.

When one creates a function with the `def` statement, is name is bound on the local namespace. If only globals is given, `locals` actually defaults to be the same dictionary.

If you do not pass a `globals` parameter to exec it will use the global namespace where it is called from - the function will be set in the runniong context, just as if where typed inline, and you can just use the name you used inside the exec string. Every linter on earth and some other tools will yell at you.

If you simply pass an ordinary dictionary as he `globals` parameter, you can retrieve your function from there:

```
from textwrap import dedent as D
#use of dedent will allow you to keep identation inside the string
# conforming to the indentation outside

def my_func():
    namespace = {}
    exec(D("""\
        def my_collate_fn():
            pass
    """), namespace)
    return namespace["my_collate_fn"]
```

The bad news: this is even less pickable than a lambda (if that is possible).

If you have to pass functions around that have to be passed as arguments
to sub-processes (for which the internal mechanism is pickling the function), just declare a plain, named function, at global scope, with `def`. Pickle will do its best to find the function and pass it around by using its `__qualname__`, and it should work in most cases - just keep it simple.